# How can I set the cursor to the end of current line in ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to add a widget in the ckeditor, if I add it directly, it will separate current line into two lines, I want to add it in the next line. How could I move the cursor to the end of current line first?

Answer (score 0):

After a whole morning work, at last I found a solution, the code is like this

```
var sel = editor.getSelection();
var range = sel.getRanges()[0];
var node = range.getNextNode();
range.setStartAt(node, CKEDITOR.POSITION_BEFORE_END);
range.setEndAt(node, CKEDITOR.POSITION_BEFORE_END);
```

Now, if you do the insertText like this

```
editor.insertText('test');
```

The test text will be inserted into the next line.